# Running Pycharm from a relative path

Tags: python, pycharm

Assuming I have a project folder `C:\Project`.

I have a python script that has to be run (in the terminal) as:

```
# Switch to the root folder and run the script (script lies in C:\Project\examples\)
cd C:\Project 
python ./examples/script.py
```

However, inside Pycharm I am unable to figure out the configuration, as I always right-click on `script.py` and then debug, thus giving me relative path errors

How do I reconfigure the project such that upon execution, it does exactly the way I do it in the command line?

Comment: In your pycharm IDE, in the top right there is a configurations section. Have you added your Python configuration with the path to your script?

Answer (score 0):

Via temrinal, your working directory is C:\Project. 
In case of pycharm,it is not. Hence, on top right, edit the configuration and set the correct working directory.

[image]